# can we use couchdb for web application development?

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb

I was wondering whether we can use java script for application development and use couchdb to serve it. I was also imagining jquery as the java script library. Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

Check out using CouchApp. CouchApp allows you to build your application in JavaScript and host it out of CouchDB. Its a great way to learn CouchDB and its a very rapid development environment.

[CouchApp](http://couchapp.org/page/index)

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Following is a link to a blogging project being developed with couchdb as the backend and PHP as the front. Its open source so you might get some ideas by looking at its code.
[Arik Blogging Software](http://github.com/Madisonw/Arik)

Answer (score 1):

Like others pointed out, CouchApps are one of they key features of CouchDB. CouchDB's built-in admin interface “Futon” is built that way. — The example application in CouchDB: The Definitive Guide (free online book) is also a CouchApp: http://guide.couchdb.org/